# Multiple calls using SIP.js (version 0.13.7)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sip, sipjs

I am using `sip.js (version 0.13.7)` for making a voice call.

I get media stream & attaching it as follows:

```
let mediaStream


  getMedia() {
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia(
        { audio: true, video: false },
        function(stream) {
          mediaStream = stream
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log('error in getUserMedia: ' + err.name)
        }
      )
    } else {
      console.log('getUserMedia not supported')
    }
  }

  handleInvite(session) {
    handleMedia(session)
    session.accept(mediaStream)
  }

  handleMedia(session) {
    session.on('trackAdded', function() {
      var remoteStream = new MediaStream()
      var pc = session.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection
      pc.getReceivers().forEach(receiver => {
        remoteStream.addTrack(receiver.track)
      })
      incomingAudioEl.srcObject = remoteStream
      incomingAudioEl.play()
    })
  }
```

It is working well for single call, but I am not able to make multiple simultaneous call, event if I try to call `handleInvite()` with new session, there is no audio & only first call is audible.

There is no good documentation about how to do this on sip.js website & many solutions availble online are previous incompatible versions.

When I search for "sip.js multiple calls" on Google, first result comes is https://sipjs.com/guides/reuse-mediastreams/, which is a non existing page.

**Note:**
I was able to make two simultaneous using older sip version, i.e. 0.7.0, but not with the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple audios worked for me when I stop/pause current audio & remove `srcObject` from audio element & then assign new tracks. So now my `handleMedia` function looks as follows:

```
  handleMedia(session) {
    session.on('trackAdded', function() {
      incomingAudioEl.pause()
      incomingAudioEl.srcObject = null
      var remoteStream = new MediaStream()
      var pc = session.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection
      pc.getReceivers().forEach(receiver => {
        remoteStream.addTrack(receiver.track)
      })
      incomingAudioEl.srcObject = remoteStream
      incomingAudioEl.play()
    })
  }
```